# Restoring Active Directory if old server is defective

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, domain

My Active Directory server/domain controller has a hardware defect and does not run anymore. Unfortunately I don't have any secondary controller, so the whole domain isn't available anymore.

I do have backup of the disk. Is it possible to set up a new windows server from scratch and, based on the disk backup of the old server, setup an active directory domain such that it is recognized as the same domain as it was before? (I.e. no need to reconfigure any clients or other servers in the domain?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're essentially trying to do is to [restore Active Directory](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727048.aspx)?

[For 2003](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc740010%28WS.10%29.aspx) and possibly the [direct link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782127%28WS.10%29.aspx) you need

Comment: Thanks, indeed I found what I was looking for, precisely in http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782127(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Excellent, good luck!